# How to match objects in Powershell Azure VMs

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I am currently trying to match an object in powershell but getting blank output and I am not sure why. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to match $resourceIDs with the Get-AzVM command. Sample output of resourceIDs and both "Get-AzVM.ID is as follows

```
/subscriptions/00/resourcegroups/rg-vm1/providers/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/az-vm1
```

And here is the code I am running that is getting blank output. Matching the string above to the Get-AzVM command below works but when I do it with a variable there is blank output.

```
$resourceIDs =((Get-AzPolicyState -Filter "ComplianceState eq 'NonCompliant'" | Where-Object {$_.PolicyDefinitionReferenceId -eq "azure backup should be enabled for virtual machines_1"} | Where-Object {$_.SubscriptionId -eq ""}).resourceID)
Get-AzVM | Where-Object{$_.Id -match $resourceIDs}
```

Edit: passing `Get-AzVM | Where-Object{$_.Id -eq $resourceIDs[0]}` 
works, now I will have to figure out how to loop through all $resourceIDs

Edit: `Get-AzVM | Where-Object{$_.Id -in $resourceIDs}`

Thanks a lot everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.1) loop,

```
$resourceIDs =((Get-AzPolicyState -Filter "ComplianceState eq 'NonCompliant'" | Where-Object {$_.PolicyDefinitionReferenceId -eq "azure backup should be enabled for virtual machines_1"} | Where-Object {$_.SubscriptionId -eq ""}).resourceID)

foreach ( $id in $resourceIDs) 

{

Get-AzVM | Where-Object{$_.Id -in $id}

}
```